# How to convert Avro Logical type timestamp-millis to Avro Logical Type date using UpdateRecord in Apache Nifi?

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-nifi, avro

I am loading the data from Oracle to Bigquery. I wanted to add an additional column in Bigquery table based on the existing column in Oracle.

I created a simple flow. `ExecuteSQL ->UpdateRecord -> PutBigQueryBatch`

In Oracle, I have A(string), B(string), and C(timestamp) columns.

For testing if this flow works, I created a new property '/D' in `UpdateRecord` with the value '/A'. The output data had the additional column D with the value same as A(string). This worked perfectly.

For testing if this flow works, I created a new property '/D' in `UpdateRecord` with the value '/C'. The output data had the additional column D with the value same as C(AVRO logical type timestamp-millis). This worked as well.

I want to upload the data to Bigquery but D column as a BigQuery Date data type instead of BigQuery Timestamp data type though.

How to convert the Avro logical type Timestamp-millis to Avro logical type Date?

Example:

Oracle:

```
            A            |            B            |            C                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            1            |            2            |2013-12-10T13:24:40.000Z
```

Bigquery:

```
            A            |            B            |            C             |        D       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            1            |            2            | 2013-12-10T13:24:40.000Z |    2013-12-10
```

Output Schema in the 'field' from `ExecuteSQL`:

```
{ "name": "A",  "type": ["null","string"] },
{ "name": "C",  "type": { "type" : "string","logicalType" : "timestamp-millis" } },
{ "name": "B",  "type": ["null","string"] }
```

Comment: Do you have "Use Avro Logical Types" set to true in ExecuteSQL? and also can you show the schema that is produced by ExecuteSQL? You can put a ConvertRecord right after ExecuteSQL, with AvroReader using embedded schema and AvroWrite with "Set 'avro.schema' Attribute" which will put the schema string into that attribute, then send to a LogAttribute processor and check nifi-app.log

Comment: I do have 'Use AVRO logical type' set to 'True'. I have added schema in the description.